# Deriving the $E=g\cdot Q\cdot h\cdot t$ formula for hydraulic energy

Tags: energy, power

**Goal**. Derive  $E=g\cdot Q\cdot h\cdot t$ where $g, Q, h$ and $t$ are the gravitational acceleration $9.8m/s^2$, the volumetric flow rate in $m^3/s$, the height in meters from the reservoir to the turbine and the time in seconds respectively.

**Attempt.** I have done quite a lot of research but found nothing much, so my very basic thoughts were to start from the $E=P\cdot t$, where $P$ is the hydraulic power in $kW$, and $E$ the theoretical energy obtained in $kWh$, and then as the hydraulic power comes from having initially a certain mecanical energy, hence $P=\frac{W}{t}$, where $W$ is the work done in Joules and $P$ the power in Joules. But I'm pretty stuck here, maybe wondering if someone could shine a light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the energy of falling water or anything else is E=mgh
1m^3 water has a mass of 1t=1000kg
and Q*t is the  volume falling down in time t. without changing Q to a mass the equation is not an energy  just proportional to energy since it has the dimension m^4/s^2  and not J=kgm^2/s^2